# joomla autogenerated css classes

Tags: joomla

i want to make a new joomla template, i dropped into that but i am confused now.
i want to know where is the joomla autogenerated css class list.
for example i insert a module in template and what is the css class for example for menu title or the css class for search input box or what is the default css class for readmore link in main.
i found a little in joomla doc but i want the whole list

Answer (score 2):

I fail to understand how you are prepared to make a Joomla template which is far more complex than a plain CSS template, yet you are unable to find the necessary CSS files. You said you wanted to make a new template therefore shouldn't **you** know where you have put the CSS file?

You are in dire need of `Firebug` for starters. Have a look at all it's features. It will help you to find CSS files and the specific line you need to edit.

I assume you are editing someone elses template in which case this is the sort of location you will be looking for.

```
templates/you_template/css/file.css
```

It varies with different template so I suggest you download Firebug as I suggested above.

Comment: i know that, i want to make a new template from scratch,for example what is the css class for readmore link in posts to edit?

Comment: It's probably "readmore" or something, but starting with the default css file would be the logical place to begin looking and *learning*.